# Won't boot (drop to busybox) after kernel upgrade (with encrypted disks)

Tags: boot, 16.04, encryption, luks

I have two systems - a 14.04.03 LTS and 16.04 LTS, both of which are not booting after recent kernel upgrades. Any help would be appreciated - I'm no expert, but it seems to me like the new kernel just isn't seeing the encrypted filesystems at boot time.

For both systems, I used the installer to encrypt the boot drive. Later, I added a second disk, encrypted using LUKS, automounted at boot time using a keyfile. I (roughly - was done after system was installed and booted) followed the instructions here:

https://www.martineve.com/2012/11/02/luks-encrypting-multiple-partitions-on-debianubuntu-with-a-single-passphrase/

Here's some more details of the systems:

**For the 16.04 LTS system:**

Hardware is an mSATA SSD on `/dev/sdb`, which Ubuntu was installed on using the automatic partition setup (`/` and swap). A 500GB Sata drive on `/dev/sda` is used for `/data` - after system was up and running, luks partition was created and set to auto mount on boot with a keyfile.

```
$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 X86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /boot was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=5039XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-d2b4XXXXXXXX /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=1DXX-XX4D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077        0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

# encrypted disk /data (unlocked with keyfile
/dev/mapper/data_crypt  /data   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1

$ cat /etc/crypttab 
sdb3_crypt UUID=0bg9rz-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXqvBH none luks
data_crypt UUID=453cXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-6926XXXXXXXX /root/<keyfile> luks
```

When `4.4.0-21` is selected from grub, a password prompt to unlock `sdb3_crypt` comes up straight away. The system then hangs at the ubuntu startup prompt. Pressing delete shows the following error message. After a few minutes the system actually does boot, and `data_crypt` is mounted on `/data` as expected

```
[ 2.091698] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] ERROR uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder a
[ 2.091735] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] ERROR PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: no such file or directory:
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: no such file or directory:
WARNING: failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean 488960/6750209 files, 11825728/26996736 blocks
[  ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0bg9rZ\X2deNSE\x2d1E8u\x2XXXXX\x2XXXXX\x2XXXX\x2dZpqvBH.device (xxS / 1min 30s)
```

From the Grub menu, selecting either 4.4.0-22 or  4.4.0-24 and then pressing delete shows the following information (transcribed):

```
[ 2.091698] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] ERROR uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder a
[ 2.091735] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] ERROR PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: no such file or directory:
WARNING: failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while.
```

The last 3 lines repeat maybe 30 times, and after a few minutes drops to a busybox shell. Manually running `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb3 sdb3_crypt` (and entering passphrase) is ok, but then I can't mount this (probably because it is in initramfs and I don't know what I'm doing there).

Deleting lines relating to `data_crypt` from `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` makes no difference, so I don't think this is related to the automount of this disk causing issues.

I have also tried re-creating the initramfs for these kernels, which has not made any difference.

I am also experiencing a similar problem on a 14.04.03 LTS system as described below, but can't provide exact details (it is the system I'm posting this from).

**For 14.04.03 LTS System:**

Hardware is an NVMe SSD for `/` and swap, and a 1TB SATA disk for `/data`. Again, Ubuntu was installed onto the SSD, and then later the SATA drive was connected, set up as an encrypted partition using luks, then added to automount at boot with a keyfile.

packages for xenial kernel have been installed:

- `linux-generic-lts-xenial`
- `linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial`
- `linux-image-generic-lts-xenial`

Command output:

```
Linux hostname 4.2.0-36-generic #42~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 13 17:27:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/fstab

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=0657XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1be3XXXXXXXX /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2

# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=AEXX-XX66  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

# encrypted disk /data (unlocked with keyfile
/dev/mapper/data_crypt  /data   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1

$ cat /etc/crypttab 
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=61235695-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-962cXXXXXXXX none luks,discard
data_crypt UUID=2e92XXXX-XX57-XXXX-XXXX-af9fXXXXXXXX /root/<keyfile> luks
```

Any of the 4.4 series kernels fails to boot. The 4.2 series kernel boots fine though.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured it out.

The UUID of sdb3_crypt (where / and swap are located) somehow wasn't right in /etc/crypttab. I verified this by comparing the UUIDs listed in /etc/crypttab with those listed in /dev/disk/by-uuid/. No idea how that got wrong, but I must have fat fingered it somewhere along the way.

I corrected /etc/crypttab with the correct UUID of /dev/sdb3, then updated the initramfs ($update-initramfs -c -k 4.4.0-24-generic). Reboot and now it works ok.

Comment: Having the exact same issue with 16.10 and moving from kernel 4.4 to 4.8.

Comment: Does your /etc/crypttab take the UUID from sda3 or from sda3_crypt? I have two different UUID's when checking with lsblk -o +UUID

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem except my `/etc/crypttab` was completely missing.  Recently I'd upgraded my mechanical hard drive to a SSD.  On both I have everything but `/boot` encrypted, and the boot process was working just fine.  Also, I checked a backup from a few weeks prior, and crypttab was there then.

I followed the answer to this post to fix my problem.

[Reinstall to existing encrypted partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853078/reinstall-to-existing-encrypted-partitions)

Note the comment re three of the mounts.  These are wrong and should be:

```
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/ubuntu/dev
# mount --bind /sys /mnt/ubuntu/sys
# mount -t proc none /mnt/ubuntu/proc
```

Also, note that the UUID in crypttab must be for the container that contains the LUKS volume (in my case `/dev/sda5`), not for the LUKS volume after is is decrypted.  (It says this, but I missed it the first time around, so I thought I'd point this out.)

Final note, gotta say that this poor behavior on the part of the updater - rendering the computer unbootable - is the kind of problem that keeps Linux from getting a wider audience among typical desktop users.